# Bash scripts. How to select python environment?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

every time I need to start a Django server, I have to do the following:

```
cd to some directory
source env/bin/activate
python manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8000
```

How could I simplify this process by creating a script that would start the server once executed.

I tried to create `.sh` script with, but I failed to change Python environment with source command.

Then I tried to create `.py` file and execute commands with `os.system()`, but `virtualenv` did not seem to have been initiated.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error you get when `source env/bin/activate` fails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as a shell function rather than as a script:

```
djangoserver() {
    cd $1
    source env/bin/activate && python manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8000
}
```

This should be functionally equivalent to running it at the command line.

You could put the same lines inside a shell script, in which case the 'source' command would be local to the shell script. That would probably be a good thing, as long as there aren't variables that you want to keep in scope after you run the script.

Comment: If you call the python interpreter from the virtualenv, you don't need to use the 'activate' script: some_directory/env/bin/python manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:8000